# WebHost restarting and losing token validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-identity

I'm having some problems with the process of confirming the email with a token, the problem seems like the token becomes invalid before the real expiration. From some tests seems like after some time passes, the webhost shut down itself, and when it restart the token become invalid. The service that handle the creation and verification of the token is `Scoped`. Is there any way to prevent the token from expiring before the actual expiration date?

UserService:

```
public async Task<CreateUserResponse> CreateUser(User user)
        {
            var res = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
            var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            return new CreateUserResponse
            {
                User = user,
                Token = token.UrlSafeEncode()
            };
        }

// token confirmation in other method:
            var res = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token.UrlSafeDecode());
```

Startup:

```
    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(config => { config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; })
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 2):

Had an issue with persistent auth cookies being invalidated on restart. Maybe related? The solution was to persist the data protection key so that it survived restarts (and across multiple instances).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2